# Как переоформить эту часть кода в виде генератора словарей, пытаюсь оптимизировать свое решение

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = 5  
lst = '-1 0 4 0 3'.split(' ')  
dct = {} 
for i in range(s):
    if str(lst[i]) not in dct:
        dct[lst[i]] = [str(i)]
    else:
        dct[lst[i]].append(str(i))
print(dct)  #{'-1': ['0'], '0': ['1', '3'], '4': ['2'], '3': ['4']}
```

Comment: Не могу понять, как оформить else в генераторе, т.к. там идет обновление значение ключа, если такой ключ уже был добавлен в словарь. Подскажите, кому не трудно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто оптимизировать, то через `enumerate'

```
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    if x not in dct:
        dct[x] = []
    dct[x].append(str(i))
```

dict comprehension не заработает, т.к. он только создает новые, но не имеет доступа к предыдущим элементам/ключам словаря.

Comment: спасибо большое! теперь понял, думал, что это возможно. Да, у меня не проходит решение по скорости на одном из курсов. Не знаю что сделать такого, чтобы код работал быстрее, алгоритм написан, вроде как, правильно. Вот и мучаюсь.

Comment: @Ste_kd Теоретически, здесь трижды происходит поиск по ключу. Маловероятно что поможет, но попробуйте вначале создать словарь целиком `dct.fromkeys(set(lst), [])`, а затем просто append без всяких проверок.

Comment: Я просто заменил свой цикл на ваш, и о чудо, спустя сутки мучений, мое решение наконец принялось) посмотрел что такое enumerate. Буду знать, задача была на поиск вершины в дереве. Спасибо еще раз